# Google Sheets Scripts: How can I select a range of values and apply a new unique value to each cell?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I'm sure this has been asked to death and I've done some experimenting myself with trial/error. I'm novice-level with coding, so I'm sure the way I've gone about it is very archaic and messy.

I'm looking to add a UI button where I can select a range of cells, and the script function takes the range of cells and their values (let's say; Walmart Hwy99, Fred Meyer Hwy99), and changes the cell's value to a new one (*hyperlink formula below*) for every cell. So far I have a function that works if you select a single cell, but not a range of cells.

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('My Functions Button')
        .addItem('GoogleMapsSingle', 'singleGoogleMaps')
        .addItem('GoogleMapsMulti', 'multiGoogleMaps')
        .addToUi();
}


function singleGoogleMaps() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

Logger.log('Current Cell: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().getA1Notation());

var currentCellValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  if(currentCellValue != ""){
    var newCellValue = '=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query='+ currentCellValue+'"'+','+'"'+currentCellValue+'"'+')'
    Logger.log('column: ' + SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation() + currentCellValue);
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell().setValue(newCellValue) 
    }

}
```

I'm probably doing this all wrong, so if there's an easier way, I'd love to learn.

Comment: [Spreadsheet.getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveRange())

Comment: [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)